# I have a data and I need to Calculate how many times the median price has been in the open range (160,170).I am just starting to learn Python

Tags: python

```
ZILLOW/C25499_MLPFAH - Value
Date    
2013-04-30  178.571429
2013-05-31  178.571429
2013-06-30  185.380865
2013-07-31  176.747442
2013-08-31  166.666667
2013-09-30  167.599502
2013-10-31  169.025157
2013-11-30  160.929092
2013-12-31  165.282392
2014-01-31  167.153775
2014-02-28  166.666667
2014-03-31  172.686604
2014-04-30  172.207447
2014-05-31  161.466408
2014-06-30  156.976744
2014-07-31  142.410714
2014-08-31  144.152523
2014-09-30  145.656780
2014-10-31  150.291745
2014-11-30  152.343542
2014-12-31  152.343542
2015-01-31  150.387968
2015-02-28  154.441006
2015-03-31  157.130952
2015-04-30  154.761905
2015-05-31  149.999583
2015-06-30  148.054146
2015-07-31  152.357673
2015-08-31  148.054146
2015-09-30  154.715762
2015-10-31  165.719697
2015-11-30  165.719697
2015-12-31  158.990168
2016-01-31  158.990168
2016-02-29  146.204168
2016-03-31  148.255814
2016-04-30  145.340150
2016-05-31  144.152523
2016-06-30  144.152523
2016-07-31  153.556496
2016-08-31  157.471093
2016-09-30  166.272727
2016-10-31  171.289349
2016-11-30  166.272727
2016-12-31  164.085821
2017-01-31  155.586081
2017-02-28  149.224486
2017-03-31  149.107143
2017-04-30  151.785714
2017-05-31  149.107143
2017-06-30  151.903057
2017-07-31  151.903057
2017-08-31  152.020400
2017-09-30  151.477833
2017-10-31  145.813048
2017-11-30  150.843468
2017-12-31  146.829969
2018-01-31  147.846890
2018-02-28  150.843468
2018-03-31  146.920361
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried ?

Comment: This is not the SO concept - you have a task and we solve it for you. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question. At least, you should specify the input and expected output, maybe which library you intend to use.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = '''2013-04-30    178.571429
2013-05-31  178.571429
2013-06-30  185.380865
2013-07-31  176.747442
2013-08-31  166.666667
2013-09-30  167.599502
2013-10-31  169.025157
2013-11-30  160.929092
2013-12-31  165.282392
2014-01-31  167.153775
2014-02-28  166.666667
2014-03-31  172.686604
2014-04-30  172.207447
2014-05-31  161.466408
2014-06-30  156.976744
2014-07-31  142.410714
2014-08-31  144.152523
2014-09-30  145.656780
2014-10-31  150.291745
2014-11-30  152.343542
2014-12-31  152.343542
2015-01-31  150.387968
2015-02-28  154.441006
2015-03-31  157.130952
2015-04-30  154.761905
2015-05-31  149.999583
2015-06-30  148.054146
2015-07-31  152.357673
2015-08-31  148.054146
2015-09-30  154.715762
2015-10-31  165.719697
2015-11-30  165.719697
2015-12-31  158.990168
2016-01-31  158.990168
2016-02-29  146.204168
2016-03-31  148.255814
2016-04-30  145.340150
2016-05-31  144.152523
2016-06-30  144.152523
2016-07-31  153.556496
2016-08-31  157.471093
2016-09-30  166.272727
2016-10-31  171.289349
2016-11-30  166.272727
2016-12-31  164.085821
2017-01-31  155.586081
2017-02-28  149.224486
2017-03-31  149.107143
2017-04-30  151.785714
2017-05-31  149.107143
2017-06-30  151.903057
2017-07-31  151.903057
2017-08-31  152.020400
2017-09-30  151.477833
2017-10-31  145.813048
2017-11-30  150.843468
2017-12-31  146.829969
2018-01-31  147.846890
2018-02-28  150.843468
2018-03-31  146.920361'''
print(len([p for p in [float(r.split()[1]) for r in data.split('\n')] if p >= 160 and p <= 170]))
```

This outputs `13`.